# Recoding numeric values

Tags: r

I have a numeric variable fear

```
 3    4    5    6    7 
 412  883 1350  920  305
```

I would like to recode the values 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,

I have tried

```
fear(revalue(fear,c("3" = "0", "4" = "1", "5" = "2", "6" = "3", "7" = "4")))
```

But it I get the Error could not find function fear, 
how can I recode the values successfully? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just reset the names? `names(fear) <- 0:4`

Comment: If they're factors do what @RichScriven suggested. If you're counting the number of numeric values just subtract 3 from each value.

Comment: `names()` will not work with factors - you have to use `levels(x) <- 0:4`

Comment: I was just going off OP's statement:  *I have a numeric variable ...*

Comment: You really need to edit with the results of `dput(fear)`.